# Complete with continuity a piecewise function

Tags: smooth-functions, numerical-calculus, piecewise-continuity

Good morning, I have been working with piecewise functions lately.
I am trying to completethis piecewise function, in order to make it smooth, with both first and second derivative smooth as well (continuous).
The function im working with is
$$ f_\delta(\tau):= 
        \begin{cases}
            \hspace{0.3 cm} 0 \hspace{0.5 cm} \text{ if } \hspace{0.3 cm} \tau \geq \delta\\
            - \frac{1}{\tau^2} \hspace{0.3 cm} \text{ if } 0 < \tau \leq \frac{\delta}{2}
        \end{cases} \\ 
f_\delta'(\tau) \geq 0 \hspace{1.0 cm} \forall \tau \in (0, \delta]$$
this applies for all $$\delta > 0$$
Does anyone have a solution?.

Most importantly, is there a way to solve a more general problem like this one? (some constructive pattern in literature)
Many thanks in advance.